# In Ruby, inside a class method, is self the class or an instance?

Tags: ruby, class, instance, self, class-method

I know that `self` is the instance inside of an instance method. So, then, is `self` the class inside of a class method? E.g., Will the following work in Rails?

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.cool_post
    self.find_by_name("cool")
  end
end
```

Comment: And to add to the below answers, since ruby will always evaluate the receiver as self unless specified, your above code can just call `find_by_name` without the self :)

Comment: Thank you, are there cases when it's a good idea to specify `self`? Is `self.find_by_name` the first place Ruby would look for `find_by_name`? Does it look anywhere else? What about in a globally defined method (a method defined in the file outside of a class)?

Comment: I tested it out. It seems that the order of precedence is the class method and then the globally defined method if no class method is found.

Comment: I have created a diagram showing [the method lookup order in Ruby](http://phrogz.net/RubyLibs/RubyMethodLookupFlow.png). You may find it useful.

Comment: At least in Ruby 1.9.2, ‘globally defined’ methods are actually private methods on `Object`. Try, for example: `def foo; end; Object.private_methods.include?(:foo) # => true`. This means that they basically end up at the top of the inheritance chain, and are last in order to be found.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That is correct. `self` inside a class method is the class itself. (And also inside the class definition, such as the `self` in `def self.coolpost`.)

You can easily test these tidbits with irb:

```
class Foo
  def self.bar
    puts self.inspect
  end
end

Foo.bar  # => Foo
```

Answer (score 5):

```
class Test
    def self.who_is_self
        p self
    end
end

Test.who_is_self
```

output:

> > Test

Now if you want a Rails specific solution, it's called named_scopes:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   named_scope :cool, :conditions => { :name => 'cool' }
end
```

Used like this:

```
Post.cool
```

Answer (score 5):

A lot of answers already, but here is **why** self is the class:

The dot changes `self` to whatever is before the dot. So, when you do `foo.bar` then for the `bar`-method, `self` is `foo`. There is no difference with class methods. When calling `Post.cool_post`, you'll change `self` to `Post`.

The important thing to note here is that it's not how the method is defined that determines `self`, but how it's called. This is why this works:

```
class Foo
  def self.bar
    self
  end
end

class Baz < Foo
end

Baz.bar # => Baz
```

Or this:

```
module Foo
  def bar
    self
  end
end

class Baz
  extend Foo
end

Baz.bar # => Baz
```

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: **yes**

What I like to do with these questions is just fire up an irb or ./script/console session

and then you can do the following to see the magic:

```
ruby-1.8.7-p174 > class TestTest
ruby-1.8.7-p174 ?>  def self.who_am_i
ruby-1.8.7-p174 ?>    return self
ruby-1.8.7-p174 ?>    end
ruby-1.8.7-p174 ?>  end
 => nil 
ruby-1.8.7-p174 > TestTest.who_am_i
 => TestTest
```

Happy fishing!